# using transaction in knexjs

Tags: database, knex.js

I'm using knexjs, I want to grab the data from one table and make it branch in another table (idk how to explain it well), for example i have these database

users

```
id | name | email      | stories |
1  | lala | lala@gmail |    1    |
```

story

```
id | entries | title | description |
1  |    1    |  haha |    foo      |
```

so the stories and entries are matched, everytime i add new story, it's the same as entries, example:

users

```
id | name | email      | stories |
1  | lala | lala@gmail |    2    |
```

story

```
id | entries | title | description |
1  |    1    |  haha |    foo      |
2  |    2    |  booo |    hoo      |
```

i tried to do these

```
app.post('/new-story', (req, res) => {
    const { title, category, description, mature, id} = req.body;
    const stories = db.select('stories').from('users');
    db.transaction( trx => {
        trx.insert({
            stories: stories
        })
        .into('users')
        .returning('stories')
        .then( entriesBook => {

            return trx('story')
                .returning('*')
                .insert({
                    entries: entriesBook[0],
                    title: title,
                    category: category,
                    description: description,
                    mature: mature
                })
                .then( story => {
                    res.json(story[0]);
                })
        })
        .then( trx.commit)
        .catch( trx.rollback)
    })
    .catch( err => res.status(400).json('unable to create story'))
})
```

does anyone know a better approached how to solve these?

Answer (score 0):

In principle your code should do more or less what you are trying to do. You are using the transaction in a correct manner, so you just need to debug your code and find the bugs.

At least this looks suspicious:

```
const stories = db.select('stories').from('users');
...

trx.insert({
  stories: stories
})
```

In SQL it will look something like (didn't check what it will output exactly):

```
insert into table (stories) values (select "stories" from users);
```